# Updating list's element's properties

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a class

```
class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I  have created a List of Student object as:

```
List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();
```

Three properties of the class will come from three different Data Sources. So I cannot add all properties of object at a time. I am adding the ID property as following:

```
lst.Add(new Student { ID = 1 }, new Student { ID = 2 })
```

Now I want to set the values of  the "FirstName" or "LastName" property in the existing list. How I can do this?

Comment: How do you map these "other" data sources to a student in the list, on `studentId`?

Comment: Does your `Add()` method call compiles?

Comment: You probably mean `lst.Add(new Student {ID = 1}); lst.Add(new Student{ID = 2});`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();
lst.Add(new Student { ID = 1 });
lst.Add(new Student { ID = 2 });
//Get the student you want by id then use that to populate the remaining properties 

var temp = lst.Single(l => l.ID == 1);
temp.FirstName = "fname";
temp.LastName = "lastname";
```

Comment: My favorites gotcha in LINQ: direct predicate pass to Where(), Single(), etc. :)

Comment: @abatishchev why would it use indexer when you do a lookup for property `ID` in the list?

Comment: @Magnus: Right. I mixed two method. The first will, and the second use here will not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix method `Add()` call:

```
list.Add(new Student());
```

and collection initialization syntax:

```
List<Student> list = new List<Student>
{
    new Student(),
    new Student()
};
```

---

Then

```
int index = 1;
Student student = list[index]; // may cause IndexOutOfRangeException
student.Name = "Me"; // may cause NullReferenceException
```

or shorter:

```
list[i].Name = "Me"; // may cause them both too
```

Comment: I must be missing something, but I don't understand why the exceptions would occur. How can `student.Name` cause a `NullReferenceExeption`?

Comment: @comecme: Try add a null then call. Can you add a `null` to `List<T>`? Yes, you can. In this particular case no exception will occur, my note concerns a general case.

Comment: What does that have to do with using `Add()` and initialization syntax? You can always add `null` to the list, which would cause problems later on. How do you suggest OP _does_ add students to the list?

Comment: @comecme: First part of my answer is to correct OP's syntax usage. Second (under the line) - an answer to his question how to access a list and update target instance's properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index from an element that matches with the element to update:

```
int index= MyObjectList.FindIndex(x=>x.Id==object.Id);
```

and after updating it:

```
MyObjectList[index]=object;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list.count-1 to get the last item in the list. Then you can update the properties you want.

```
List<Student> lst=new List<Student>();
lst.Add(new Student { ID = 1, FirstName = "FirstName", LastName = "LastName" });
//Then get props from other datasource
lst[lst.Count-1].FirstName="FirstName";
lst[lst.Count-1].LastName="LastName";
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use something like

Comment: on a side note lst.Add(new Student{ID=1},new Student{ID=2}); will not compile !!

Comment: @ashutosh raina UpVote. You are right, I just copied from the question without checking.

Answer (score 0):

Im only guessing here... if , doesnt work try ;

```
lst.Add(new Student{ID=2, FirstName="The", LastName="Stig"});
```

Or you can define a constructor for the Student object...

```
public Student(int mID, string mFirstName, string mLastName)
{
    ID = mID;
    FirstName = mFirstName;
    LastName = mLastName;
}
```

Then use

```
lst.Add(new Student(2, "The", "Stig"));
```

Comment: Everything is correct except you do correct OP's code and don't answer OP's question :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other data sources contains the `studentId` and all students has a last and first name.
Join the `lastNameList` and `firstNameList` collections using linq. The studentId list you dont need since the other two has that value also.

```
var list =
         (from lastName in lastNameList
         join firstName in firstNameList on lastName.studentId equals firstName.studentId
         select new Student()
         {
            .ID = lastName.studentId,
            .FirstName = firstName.Name,
            .LastName = lastName.Name
         }).ToList();
```